Как отправлять команды через mc.postToChat в mcpi
Приветсвую! Как отправлять команды на выполнение в консоль Майнкрафта через mc.postToChat в пакете mcpi? Я пытался отправить, но он выводился как текст, а не как команда.
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft

mc = Minecraft.create()

mc.postToChat("/time set day")

